# r raster how to keep Date information in the z variable

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a raster brick called ncin.brick created from a netcdf file. Here is its information

```
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 360, 720, 259200, 3652  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : /Users/gcn/Documents/workspace/ISIMIPData/data-raw/rsds_day_GFDL-ESM2M_historical_r1i1p1_EWEMBI_landonly_18610101-18701231.nc 
names      : X1861.01.01, X1861.01.02, X1861.01.03, X1861.01.04, X1861.01.05, X1861.01.06, X1861.01.07, X1861.01.08, X1861.01.09, X1861.01.10, X1861.01.11, X1861.01.12, X1861.01.13, X1861.01.14, X1861.01.15, ... 
Date       : 1861-01-01, 1870-12-31 (min, max)
varname    : rsdsAdjust
```

Note that the z variable is Date and its class is "Date"

```
head(getZ(ncin.brick))
[1] "1861-01-01" "1861-01-02" "1861-01-03" "1861-01-04" "1861-01-05" "1861-01-06"
```

Suppose I want all the layers before 1865-01-01. I can use this command

```
ncin.brick.sub <- ncin.brick[[which(getZ(ncin.brick) >= as.Date("1865-01-01")) ]]
```

The information for ncin.brick.sub is

```
dimensions : 360, 720, 259200, 2191  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names      : X1865.01.01, X1865.01.02, X1865.01.03, X1865.01.04, X1865.01.05, X1865.01.06, X1865.01.07, X1865.01.08, X1865.01.09, X1865.01.10, X1865.01.11, X1865.01.12, X1865.01.13, X1865.01.14, X1865.01.15, ...
```

Note that the Date variable is no longer there. I can add it back in with setZ. First get the Date information

```
time.temp = ncin.brick@z[["Date"]]
```

And then do the subsetting operation on it

```
time.temp.sub <- time.temp[time.temp >= as.Date("1865-01-01")]
```

Finally use this command to add it back in.

```
ncin.brick.sub2 <- setZ(ncin.brick.sub, time.temp.sub, name = "Date")
```

Now the information for ncin.brick.sub2 is below. (note that Date is now indicated as a range whereas in the original it was listed as min, max)

```
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 360, 720, 259200, 2191  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names      : X1865.01.01, X1865.01.02, X1865.01.03, X1865.01.04, X1865.01.05, X1865.01.06, X1865.01.07, X1865.01.08, X1865.01.09, X1865.01.10, X1865.01.11, X1865.01.12, X1865.01.13, X1865.01.14, X1865.01.15, ... 
Date        : 1865-01-01 - 1870-12-31 (range)
```

My question is whether there is a more straightforward way to do this, with say 1 line of code instead of many.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error on my computer and see here there was a known error when subsetting a single layer from a brick but not when subsetting multiple layers: https://github.com/rspatial/raster/issues/30 which version of raster are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.0-7.